# What is the point in which metal turns white hot during launch or reentry called?

Tags: launch, reentry, physics, identify-this-object, heat-shield

This is a slow motion film of the Sprint missle. There is a point where to skin goes white hot like a light switch. What is that called?

What metal gets white hot while keeping its shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phenomenon of a hot body emitting visible light is called [incandescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescence).

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprint_(missile)), the skin of the Sprint missile gets up to 6,200 °F (3,430 °C); it has an ablative coating that melts or burns away, carrying thermal energy away from the body of the missile beneath. The Sprint only spends a short time in flight, so the ablative layer doesn't have to be terribly thick.

Alloys like the [Inconel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconel) family are usually used for heat resistance aerospace applications; they're only good up to 1500-2000°F (815 to 1093 °C), so the ablative layer is a must.